# how to get f# signature - visual studio or vs code

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I want to be able to explicitly write type signatures in my code.

VS code will (eventually) generate sort of ghost signatures, but I actually want to explicitly take these generated signatures and type the code.

Any ideas? I could use FSI, but that can be quite a cumbersome technique.

Ideally I'd right click and "generate signature"..though that doesn't always fit peoples coding style...I tend to write code;

```
   let f : int -> string = 
      fun i -> i.ToString()
```

Comment: That has been a suggested feature for both Visual Studio and Ionide (in VS Code), but it hasn't been implemented in either yet.

Comment: In VS Code when you hover over a symbol you get a description which you can select and copy/paste into your code.

Comment: yes I've just seen this in vs code...unfortunately it takes a long long time....my types are very complex (the code is partially generated)

Comment: and it also seems to be quite unreliable...sometimes it comes up, sometimes it just gives up

Comment: the only thing that seems to work in a reasonable manner is FSI...but that requires creating a script file, referencing all the correct stuff....just seems silly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the type of an F# function using the [Compiler Services SDK](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/symbols.html).  This would require writing a custom analyzer for your projects, but it should be a reusable component that you can integrate into your development process once implemented.  The basic steps to resolve every function's type signature would be:

1. Create an F# Type Checker (`FSharpChecker`) instance.
2. Load your project options (`FSharpProjectOptions`).
3. Parse and check each file (`FSharpChecker.parseAndCheckFileInProject`).
4. Retrieve the Declarations list from each type-checker result (`FSharpCheckFileAnswer`).
5. Print the type signature (`FSharpType`) for each declaration.

Here's a quick solution I put together as a starting point:

```
#r @"FSharp.Compiler.Service.25.0.1\lib\net45\FSharp.Compiler.Service.dll"
#r @"FSharp.Compiler.Service.ProjectCracker.25.0.1\lib\net45\FSharp.Compiler.Service.ProjectCracker.dll"

open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.SourceCodeServices
open System
open System.IO

type Namespace =
    {
        Name: string
        XmlDoc: System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>
    }    

type Declaration =
| Namespace of Namespace * Declaration list
| Module of FSharpEntity * Declaration list
| Class of FSharpEntity * Declaration list
| Interface of FSharpEntity * Declaration list
| Enum of FSharpEntity * Declaration list
| Record of FSharpEntity * Declaration list
| Union of FSharpEntity * Declaration list
| Function of FSharpMemberOrFunctionOrValue
| Binding of FSharpMemberOrFunctionOrValue    

let checker = FSharpChecker.Create(1, true)

let getProject projectFile =
    ProjectCracker.GetProjectOptionsFromProjectFile(projectFile)

let private isNamespace (declaration: FSharpImplementationFileDeclaration) =
    match declaration with
    | FSharpImplementationFileDeclaration.Entity (entity, children) -> entity.IsNamespace
    | _ -> false

let rec private getDeclaration nsSoFar (declaration: FSharpImplementationFileDeclaration) =
    [
        match declaration with
        | FSharpImplementationFileDeclaration.Entity (entity, children) ->
            if entity.IsNamespace then
                if children.Length = 1 && children.Head |> isNamespace
                then match nsSoFar with
                     | Some ns -> yield! getDeclaration (Some <| sprintf "%s.%s" ns entity.DisplayName) children.Head
                     | None -> yield! getDeclaration (Some entity.DisplayName) children.Head
                else match nsSoFar with
                     | Some ns -> 
                        let nsEntity = {Name = sprintf "%s.%s" ns entity.DisplayName; XmlDoc = entity.XmlDoc}
                        yield Namespace (nsEntity, children |> List.collect (getDeclaration nsSoFar))
                     | None -> 
                        let nsEntity = {Name = entity.DisplayName; XmlDoc = entity.XmlDoc}
                        yield Namespace (nsEntity, children |> List.collect (getDeclaration nsSoFar))
            elif entity.IsClass then
                yield Class (entity, children |> List.collect (getDeclaration nsSoFar))
            elif entity.IsInterface then
                yield Interface (entity, children |> List.collect (getDeclaration nsSoFar))            
            elif entity.IsEnum then
                yield Enum (entity, children |> List.collect (getDeclaration nsSoFar))
            elif entity.IsFSharpModule then
                yield Module (entity, children |> List.collect (getDeclaration nsSoFar))
            elif entity.IsFSharpRecord then
                yield Record (entity, children |> List.collect (getDeclaration nsSoFar))
            elif entity.IsFSharpUnion then
                yield Union (entity, children |> List.collect (getDeclaration nsSoFar))
            else 
                ()                        

        | FSharpImplementationFileDeclaration.MemberOrFunctionOrValue (func, _, _) ->
            if func.IsValCompiledAsMethod
            then yield Function func
            else yield Binding func
        | _ -> ()    
    ]    

let getDeclarations (project: FSharpProjectOptions) file =
    async {
        let source = File.ReadAllText file
        let! (parseResults, checkResults) = checker.ParseAndCheckFileInProject(file, 1, source, project)

        return 
            match checkResults with
            | FSharpCheckFileAnswer.Succeeded checkInfo -> 
                match checkInfo.ImplementationFile with
                | Some implementation -> implementation.Declarations |> List.collect (getDeclaration None)
                | None -> failwithf "No Implementation Available for File %s" file
            | error -> failwithf "Error Checking File %s:\r\n%A" file error
    }    

let getDeclarationsForScript file =
    async {
        let source = File.ReadAllText file        
        let! (project, _) = checker.GetProjectOptionsFromScript(file, source)
        return! getDeclarations project file
    }
```

Then, if we have a sample script file called "Test.fsx" with a function like your example inside it (`let f i = sprintf "%d" i`), we can print the function's signature like so:

```
let getTypeName (t: FSharpType) =
    t.Format(FSharpDisplayContext.Empty).Replace("Microsoft.FSharp.Core.", "")

let rec printFunctionSignatures declarations =
    for declaration in declarations do
        match declaration with
        | Namespace (_, ds) -> printFunctionSignatures ds
        | Module (_, ds) -> printFunctionSignatures ds
        | Function f -> f.FullType |> getTypeName |> printfn "%s: %s" f.DisplayName
        | _ -> () // Handle all the other cases

getDeclarationsForScript "Test.fsx" 
|> Async.RunSynchronously
|> printFunctionSignatures
```

This will pint out:

`f: int -> string`